# Changing non-root user passwords from root (if you don't know the old password?)

Tags: debian, root, password-recovery

Hey, so I created a user, and he has been  sshing in and doing a lot of stuff, but he forgot his password - is there any way for me to change his password without knowing it?

Comment: you could also add his public key to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` for passwordless authentication...

Answer (score 12):

Oh, it's

```
passwd username
```

Sorry for asking and answering my own question. :S

Comment: No problem with answering your own question - just go ahead and mark it as answered.

Comment: It doesnt let me do that, for two days.

Comment: Are you trying it from root or from your normal user? If you are doing it from your normal user it should be 'sudo passwd username' rather than 'passwd username'